# Unity and Generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inversion-of-control, unity-container

how do i register and resolve a generic object/interface in Unity?  I'm trying to stay away from the config file.

I'm looking for something like

`IEnterpriseClient<IInterface1>` to resolve to `EnterpriseClient<IInterface1>`

The class signature is

```
class EnterpriseClient<T> : IEnterpriseClient<T> where T : class
```

Thanks!

Comment: For some reason the interface didnt show in the question.  Sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty much exactly what you'd think:

```
container.RegisterType<IEnterpriseClient<IInterface1>, EnterpriseClient<IInterface1>>( ... );
```

That's if you only want that particular closed generic registered. For the open generic (not just IInterface1), you can do:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IEnterpriseClient<>), typeof(EnterpriseClient<>), ... );
```

You mentioned you'd tried this - what's not working?

Comment: Nope, thats it.  I left out the IInterface1 in the register.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Look at this question for XML configuration: [Unity 2.0 registering generic types via XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486837/unity-2-0-registering-generic-types-via-xml)

and http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/03/25/UnityDependencyInjectionOpenGenericTypes.aspx for code configuration.

Comment: I want to stay away from config files and I've tried the simple examples such as _CurrentContainer.RegisterType(typeof(IEnterpriseClient<>),                                            typeof(EnterpriseClient<>)