# Unity 2.0 Registering generic via config

Tags: .net, generics, dependency-injection, unity-container, config

I'm still having difficulty getting unity to register my generic dependency even after referring to [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486837/unity-2-0-registering-generic-types-via-xml) post.

My code is simpler in that it doesn't implement the `GenericRepository<T>` and is as follows:

```
public interface ISerializer<T> where T : class
{
    ...
}

public class WorkflowSerializer : ISerializer<XmlFormWorkflow>
{
...
}

public class WorkflowManager
{
    private readonly ISerializer<XMLFormWorkflow> _serializer;

    public WorkflowManager(ISerializer<XmlFormWorkflow> serializer)
    {
         _serializer = serializer;
    }
}
```

The conig file I am using looks as follows:

```
<unity>
  <alias alias="ISerializer" type="Common.ISerializer`1, Common" />
  <alias alias="WorkflowSerializer" type="Common.WorkflowSerializer, Common" />
  <alias alias="XMLFormWorkflow" type="Common.XMLFormWorkflow, Common" />
  <container>
    <register type="ISerializer[XMLFormWorkflow]" mapTo="WorkflowSerializer" />
  </container>
</unity>
```

The error that I am getting is as follows:

```
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Business.WorkflowManager", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type,     Common.ISerializer`1[Common.XMLFormWorkflow], is an interface and cannot be constructed.     Are you missing a type mapping?
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:
  Resolving parameter "serializer" of constructor Business.WorkflowManager(Common.ISerializer`1[[Common.XMLFormWorkflow, Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] serializer)
  Resolving Common.ISerializer`1[Common.XMLFormWorkflow],(none)
```

I've tried including the type inside the alias

```
<alias alias="ISerializer" type="Common.ISerializer`1[[Common.XMLFormWorkflow, Common]], Common" />
```

but that does not seem to work either. I could strongly type `WorkflowSerializer` inside my `WorkflowManager` however it is something I would like to avoid.

I just hope I didn't overlook something simple. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I neglected to check the namespace that my `WorkflowManager` class was under. ReSharper likes to associate the namespace of the file with the respective folder that the file is found under. In my case the issue was :

```
namespace Common.Implementations
{
    public class WorkflowSerializer : ISerializer<XMLFormWorkflow>
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

Once I removed the `.Implementations` from the namespace, unity was able to build dependencies successfully.

Hope my brain fart helps one of you in the long run.